# Detect when TaskScheduler 'deadlocks' attempting to Run a thread-based Task

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task

Given a situation where N long-running tasks are created on TaskScheduler.Default (using the ThreadPool) with a maximum concurrency of N.

However, the completion of these N tasks are dependent upon another task which has not yet started; this new task cannot be run because the N existing tasks are running, each consuming their own thread.

Is - and if not, how can - this form of 'deadlock' situation reported? For example, is there a callback which occurs when a task *cannot* be started (within some amount of time)?